# Вызов php-функции из Python

Tags: php, python, python-3.x, flask

Появился такой вопрос: есть у меня, к примеру, php файл (**something.php**), внутри которого есть несколько функций (пусть все они будут с параметрами):

```php
#пример одной функции
function get_something($smth1, $smth2){
    #всякий разный код 
    return something;
}
```

Потом в Python пишу вот так:

```python
def get_rate_stars_message(smth1, smth2):
    p = subprocess.call(["php", "/путь/к/файлу/something.php"])
    script_response = subprocess.check_output(["php", "/путь/к/файлу/something.php"])
```

Вот тут, собственно, я и остановился.

Файл читается, все хорошо, но как вызвать функцию `function get_something($smth1, $smth2)` и передать ей параметры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак не вызывать. 
Поместить код функции в отдельный файл, и вызывать его целиком.
Параметры в файле принимать через `$argv`

Ну или если так прям хочется несколько функций в файле, то опять же, имя функции передавать первым параметром и вызывать

```
$func = $argv[1];
if (!in_array($func, array('foo', 'bar'))) die ('Undefined function');
$func($argv[2],$argv[3]);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень помог. Реализовал сначала как вы посоветовали, потом нашел еще более простой метод через `requests` Документация творит чудеса!

Comment: @FlyingPig Вы можете оформить своё решение в виде ответа к собственному вопросу, в таком случае это может помочь тем, у кого возникла такая же проблема.

Answer (score 0):

function get_something($smth1, $smth2){
    ... 
    return something;
}

$func = argv[1]
echo $func(argv[2],argv[3])

---

def get_rate_stars_message(smth1, smth2):
    args=["/usr/bin/php","/home/user/something.php","smth1","smth2"]
    data = subprocess.check_output(args, universal_newlines=True)
    print(data)

Comment: Лучше форматировать код при ответе и сопровождать его пояснениями.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```py
import os, sys, subprocess, json

def is_json(myjson):
    try:
        json_object = json.loads(myjson)
    except ValueError as ve:
        return False
    return True

def getPopen(f):
    p = os.popen(f)
    rezult = p.read().strip()
    if is_json(rezult):
        return json.loads(rezult)
    else:
        return rezult

phpinput = getPopen("/......./my.php arg1 arg2")
print(phpinput)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]